# Show several values (by formulas) in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have this :

[image]

Nothing hard to find the city with the formula, and I can show all with Something like this :

```
=INDEX($B:$B;MATCH(F1;$A:$A;0);0)&"/"&INDEX($C:$C;MATCH(F1;$A:$A;0);0)&"/"&INDEX($D:$D;MATCH(F1;$A:$A;0);0)
```

But then, if there is only one city it will write : Paris//

How delete this / if there is not 3 city ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have office365, you can use the TEXTJOIN function in combination with INDEX and MATCH. Something like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;INDEX(B:D;MATCH(F1;A:A;0);0))
```

Comment: `TEXTJOIN` in french excel is `JOINDRE.TEXTE` Also see my edit.

Comment: It is working very well ! And do you know if I need to do some calcul on it ? like Paris/2, Santender/2 ?

Comment: The formula should work as is, without extra calculations. Just paste in G1 and copy down.

Comment: I mean, if I want to do formulas on this answer. like I have in a cell : Paris, Santender. I want to do : Paris-1, Santender + 2...

Answer (score 0):

You already have an elegant solution. In case if you want to have an approach without `TEXTJOIN` then modify it like below:

`=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(INDEX($B:$B;MATCH(F1;$A:$A;0);0)&" "&INDEX($C:$C;MATCH(F1;$A:$A;0);0)&" "&INDEX($D:$D;MATCH(F1;$A:$A;0);0))," ","/")`